# Combine Tuple and Tuples Tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-synonyms

Does it make sense to combine the [tuple](/questions/tagged/tuple) and [tuples](/questions/tagged/tuples) tag on SO? Or make Tuples a synonym of Tuple?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok, I merged into [tuples](/questions/tagged/tuples) and set up a synonym. We typically prefer the plural form of the tag.

Answer (score 0):

I agree. I just noticed [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2339863/use-map-and-stuff-on-scala-tuples), which was tagged with both of them.