# Merge stdtuple tag into tuples?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, tag-synonyms

See also this question: [Combine Tuple and Tuples Tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81713/combine-tuple-and-tuples-tag)

There are currently 26 questions on Stack Overflow tagged "stdtuple". All those questions are also tagged C++, and the tag name might make some sense as a reference to the name `std::tuple` in C++, but the [tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/stdtuple/info)'s description is not specific to C++.

There are 1656 questions tagged "tuples", which has a much more detailed [tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/tuples/info).

I suggest the "stdtuple" tag should be merged into "tuples". (I'm not sure whether it should be aliased, burninated, or something else.)